# Operators of std::iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have assumed that iterators had overloaded their operator+ and operator- to return an iterator. I also assumed that iterators had overloaded operator int(), which made the following compile:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(3);

std::vector<int>::iterator low = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 2);

int i = low - v.begin();
```

But when I tried assigning the result to an iterator instead of an int i got a compile error:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator i = low - v.begin();
```

Why doesnt subtracting an iterator from another result in an iterator?

I cant find any information on [cplusplus.com/reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/) or anywhere else on exactly what the interface of an iterator contains.

Comment: What would be the semantics of an iterator that was the difference of two other iterators?

Comment: You should post the compiler error.  Also, if subtracting two iterators yielded an iterator, then simple pointers (they *are* considered iterators) subtracted from each other would yield a pointer, given your logic.  But that isn't the case.

Comment: There are distance function in <iterator> return number of elements beetween two iterator

Comment: @user888379 When you put it like that, I guess it wouldnt make much sense

Comment: it will be more strange if the second one will work when the first one works lol because you cannot overload a function or an operator with the very same parameter lol

Comment: @LorenceHernandez you can do it like this  cpp.sh/8gipz

Comment: @Q-bertsuit okay i didnt know about operator int()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Why doesnt subtracting an iterator from another result in an iterator?"

Why would it, subtracting 2 pointers does not result in another pointer.

If anything I would expect it to return the distance between the 2 iterators in units of contained elements - ie an int

and a quick test shows that it does return the distance

```
vector<int> test;
test.push_back(1);
  test.push_back(2);
int d = test.begin() - test.end();
cout << d;
return 0;
```

says : -2

Comment: When thinking of an iterator as a pointer, it does make sense that subtracting one from the other would return the distance, and not another iterator/pointer. Thanks!